# AngularJS var to scope binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a beginner at this and I'm thinking the problem has to do with what they call binding to a primitive, but I don't fully grasp the concept

In my JS file, I have something like: (note that this is semi-pseudocode!)

```
var files = [];

function(name){
    files.push({ID: "Three");
}

var writetofile = angular.module("write", []);
writetofile.controller("writeCtrl",  ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.allfiles = [{ID: "One"}, {ID: "Two"}];
        $scope.getAllFiles = function(){
            $scope.allfiles.push(files);
        }
$scope.getAllFiles();
```

In my HTML file:

```
<ng-controller="writeCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="data in allfiles">
   {{data.ID}}
</div>
```

Essentially, I call the function to update the var array files, which I want to then update to the scope.variable allfiles, and print the contents out.
So far, I can successfully update files, but once I push to allfiles, nothing updates on the html. It only prints "One" , "Two" even after the update.

Comment: Im guessing `files` should be pushed to `allfiles` instead of `allsongs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `concat` or `apply` with `push` function. Try the following code:

```js
var writetofile  = angular.module('write', []);
writetofile.controller('writeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  
  var files = [];
  function name(){
      files.push({ID: "Three"});
  }
  name();
  $scope.allfiles = [{ID: "One"}, {ID: "Two"}];
  $scope.getAllFiles = function(){
    // using concat
    // $scope.allfiles = $scope.allfiles.concat(files);
    // using push apply
    [].push.apply($scope.allfiles, files);
  }
  $scope.getAllFiles();

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='write' ng-controller="writeCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="data in allfiles">
   {{data.ID}}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you trying to do correctly, You need to $watch on the list of files, then if there is a change in this array you can update the list the you repeating on in the HTML. (if it's not the same $scope array! )

but its seems that your pushing the object to a different list from the one on the view. ( if its the same list it should change by itself)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not really clear to me, I'm assuming that you're trying to update the `$scope.allFiles` list by adding it another item `{ID: "Three"}`.

What you should be doing is define the function that appends file to allFiles inside the scope, and add it directly to `$scope.allFiles`.

it should be something like this:

```
//Inside the controller
$scope.allfiles = [{ID: "One"}, {ID: "Two"}];

$scope.addToFiles = function(fileObj) {
    $scope.allfiles.push(fileObj);
}

$scope.addToFiles({ID: "Three"});
```